# Customizing VSTS Wiki with web contents

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-devops, wiki

I wanted to edit the welcome page of VSTS wiki with my own web page contents but there are lot of limitations with the provided editor. Is it possible to add our own web page as content to Microsoft VSTS Wiki page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to add our own web page as content to Microsoft VSTS
>   Wiki page?

For now we can't insert our own web pages to `VSTS Wiki` page. `VSTS Wiki` allows us to insert web links in this format `[xxx](URL...)` and create Wiki pages from `Markdown`, but if what you want is to let the web page content displayed dynamically in Wiki page, I have to say this is not supported yet.

More info about VSTS Wiki Pages you can refer to [Syntax guidance for Markdown usage in Wiki](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops) and [Add and edit wiki pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/add-edit-wiki?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser).

And it would be a good idea if `VSTS Wiki` can dynamically share the content of own web pages to avoid extra manual maintenance, so if you do like this idea, I suggest you can share your feature requirements [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) by `suggest a feature` option. If it gets enough votes, the team would consider it seriously.

Comment: If you have administrative access to the backing IIS server and IIS administrative experience, you can configure the backing IIS to serve up HTML pages from a select folder(s). We've done that to make various generated HTML-based documentation readily accessible via our Wiki. Won't work if you are "in the cloud" though.